# Seleção de colunas no Rstudio

Tags: select, r, columns

vamos supor que eu tenha uma tabela contendo muitas colunas com os seguintes nomes:
[foto com a as colunas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SS1Ls.png)

como eu faço para selecionar todas as colunas de uma vez só, sem precisar digitar o nome de uma por uma, sem usar a função select dessa forma:

```
data.df<- data%% select(coluna1,coluna2,coluna3...colunaN)
```

Answer (score 0):

Se você tem um *dataframe* chamado `data` e s[o deseja simplesmente criar uma cópia com todas as colunas pode simplesmente fazer:

```
data.df <- data
```

Agora, se `data.df` é um *dataframe* parcial de `data` é possível selecionar colunas de formas distintas:

**Por posição**

```
data.df <- 
  data %>%
  select(1:10,15:20)
```

No caso acima `data.df` terias colunas de 1 a 10 e de 15 a 20 do dataframe `data`.

**Por nome**

```
data.df <- 
  data %>%
  select(coluna1:coluna18)
```

No caso acima `data.df` terias colunas de 1 a 18 do *dataframe* `data`, porém utilizado os nomes como referência.

**Funções auxiliares**

Agora caso seja uma seleção mais complexa, em que suas colunas possuam algum tipo de padrão no nome ou ainda deseje usar os tipos das variáveis, recomendo usar funções auxiliares para seleção, fica o comando para a documentação destas funções:

```
?tidyselect::select_helpers
```